# array taking more input than definition

Tags: c, arrays

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
    printf("%d",a[i]);

    }
    for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
        printf("%d",a[i]);

    }       
    return 0;   
 }
```

*here if we give any input eg 5 then output is...
01234012345  here question is that code should give an error but insted it prints 5 which is stored in a[5] & a[5] is undeclared*

Comment: C lets you shoot yourself in the foot. In other words there's no automatic bounds checking.

Comment: Can you declare dynamically sized arrays on the stack in C?

Comment: It's _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @Nick They are called VLAs.

Comment: @Nick It's called [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and allowed since the C99 standard.

Comment: @cnicutar thanks. not sure I like the look of them!

Comment: Where does the memory get allocated? or that implementation dependent?

Comment: @Nick On the stack. But the standard doesn't say anything about the stack.. so yeah.

Comment: I look forward to the day when a C implementation chooses to use a graph, instead of a stack. This is the day that everyone talking about a "stack" will feel very foolish.